# Querying nested key-value pairs in jq without row-filtering

Tags: jq

I'm trying to query some JSON that requires unpacking key-value pairs into top-level fields in the output. However it's common for key-values to only appear in some rows in the input, in which case I want to fallback to null. Example (simplified) input:

```json
{
  "id": "123",
  "details": [
    {
      "headerText": "ignore_me",
      "rows": [
        {
          "key": "label1",
          "val": "sdhf"
        },
        {
          "key": "label2",
          "val": "fdgg"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "headerText": "only_look_at_kvs_here",
      "rows": [
        {
          "key": "label3",
          "val": "abc"
        },
        {
          "key": "label4",
          "val": "def"
        },
        {
          "key": "label5",
          "val": "qwe"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
{
  "id": "345",
  "details": [
    {
      "headerText": "ignore_me",
      "rows": [
        {
          "key": "label1",
          "val": "abc"
        },
        {
          "key": "label2",
          "val": "def"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "headerText": "only_look_at_kvs_here",
      "rows": [
        {
          "key": "label1",
          "val": "foo"
        },
        {
          "key": "label2",
          "val": "bar"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
{
  "id": "789",
  "details": [
    {
      "headerText": "ignore_me",
      "rows": [
        {
          "key": "label1",
          "val": "abc"
        },
        {
          "key": "label2",
          "val": "def"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And expected output:

```json
{
  "id": "123",
  "label1": null,
  "label2": null,
  "label3": "abc",
  "label4": "def"
}
{
  "id": "345",
  "label1": "foo",
  "label2": "bar",
  "label3": null,
  "label4": null
}
{
  "id": "789",
  "label1": null,
  "label2": null,
  "label3": null,
  "label4": null
}
```

I've tried a variety of patterns but I keep getting tripped up on jq's filtering behaviour when trying to select(...) the appropriate items in the nested arrays. My latest attempt:

```bash
jq '{id, "label1": (.details[] | select(.headerText=="only_look_at_kvs_here") | .rows[] | select(.key=="label1") | .val) }'
```

Any pointers on how best to achieve this?

Comment: Is it intended that the second object has `.deatils` instead of `.details`, and that those "deatils" contain `label1` and `label2` twice but no `label3` and `label4`, yet the output should?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've corrected the typo on details and fleshed out the example input/output a bit more to clarify. Yes it's expected that labels are present on some input objects but not others.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach which is dynamic wrt the set of labels. It first collects all labels across all objects (using `--slurp`) to prepare a "base object" with all labels preset to `null`. That way `label3` and `label4` will also be present in the second object, even though they're missing there in the input. This also assumes that in case of name clashes later occurrences should "overwrite" previous ones (as seen with the first occurrences of `label1` and `label2` in the second object). Then, the objects can be built up successively, filtering by the value of `.headerText`, and using that prepared base object (and `{id}`) as initial state.

```bash
jq -s '
  (map(.details[].rows[]) | from_entries) as $labels | .[] | reduce (
    .details[] | select(.headerText == "only_look_at_kvs_here").rows[]
  ) as {$key, $val} ({id} + $labels; .[$key] = $val)
' input.json
```

```json
{
  "id": "123",
  "label1": null,
  "label2": null,
  "label3": "abc",
  "label4": "def"
}
{
  "id": "345",
  "label1": "foo",
  "label2": "bar",
  "label3": null,
  "label4": null
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/olZybUZ-SVI)

---

**Edit:** With the updated input sample, `label5` will now be included in all of the objects, since this approach "first collects all labels" into a "base object". Here's the updated output:

```json
{
  "id": "123",
  "label1": null,
  "label2": null,
  "label3": "abc",
  "label4": "def",
  "label5": "qwe"
}
{
  "id": "345",
  "label1": "foo",
  "label2": "bar",
  "label3": null,
  "label4": null,
  "label5": null
}
{
  "id": "789",
  "label1": null,
  "label2": null,
  "label3": null,
  "label4": null,
  "label5": null
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/slD71m4v2gn)

> I don't care about all KV pairs. So KV agnostic solutions are less ideal

Then, how about statically predefining your preferred set of labels (either statically as part of the code, or on call using the `--args` option), which is then used to accordingly generate the "base object", and to ignore all other keys from the input in a second filter. With this approach, the input also no longer needs to be "slurped".

```bash
# statically as part the code
jq '
  ["label1", "label2", "label3", "label4"] as $labels | reduce (
    .details[] | select(.headerText == "only_look_at_kvs_here")
    | .rows[] | select(IN(.key; $labels[]))
  ) as {$key, $val} ({id} | .[$labels[]] = null; .[$key] = $val)
' input.json

# on call using the `--args` option
jq '
  reduce (
    .details[] | select(.headerText == "only_look_at_kvs_here")
    | .rows[] | select(IN(.key; $ARGS.positional[]))
  ) as {$key, $val} ({id} | .[$ARGS.positional[]] = null; .[$key] = $val)
' input.json --args label1 label2 label3 label4
```

```json
{
  "id": "123",
  "label1": null,
  "label2": null,
  "label3": "abc",
  "label4": "def"
}
{
  "id": "345",
  "label1": "foo",
  "label2": "bar",
  "label3": null,
  "label4": null
}
{
  "id": "789",
  "label1": null,
  "label2": null,
  "label3": null,
  "label4": null
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/ZZ8w5Db55Hl) (static version)

Comment: Thanks will have a play around with this. To clarify a bit this example is somewhat oversimplified and ultimately I want to do label specific processing on the value in the KV pairs. I also don't care about all KV pairs. So KV agnostic solutions are less ideal (but still workable since I can potentially do the post-processing in a follow-up step).

Answer (score 0):

Would the following work for you?

```
{ id }
+ (
    [.details[] | select(.headerText == "only_look_at_kvs_here") | .rows[] | {key, value:.val}]
    | from_entries
    | {
        label1,
        label2,
        label3,
        label4
    }
)
```

or equivalently:

```
.id as $id
| [.details[] | select(.headerText == "only_look_at_kvs_here") | .rows[] | {key, value:.val}]
| from_entries
| {
    $id,
    label1,
    label2,
    label3,
    label4
}
```

Output (after fixing "deatils" to "details"):

```
{
  "id": "123",
  "label1": null,
  "label2": null,
  "label3": "abc",
  "label4": "def"
}
{
  "id": "345",
  "label1": "foo",
  "label2": "bar",
  "label3": null,
  "label4": null
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this appears to work well but I don't really understand how. Specifically I'm struggling to understand how this avoids my initial problem of object filtering (e.g. for the third input object in the original example, which doesn't have an only_look_at_kvs_here entry). Can you help clarify?

Comment: @DanielResnick The `select(...)` part filters the input stream, for this specific solution it only selects those elements with header text being equal to "only_look_at_kvs_here"). `[...]` collects the stream to an array again.

Answer (score 0):

You might also be interested in a [`reduce`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#Reduce)-based solution:

```
reduce (.details[] | select(.headerText == "only_look_at_kvs_here"))
as $details (
    {id, label1:null, label2:null, label3:null, label4:null};
    . + ($details.rows | map({key, value:.val}) | from_entries)
)
```